# Angular 5. How to dynamically add links to strings containing a certain tag. like '@'

Tags: html, string, angular, typescript, anchor

I have a template view which looks like this

```
<div class="post-content">
      <p>{{ post.content }}</p>
</div>
```

where post.content is a type of string.

The string may or may not contain one or more @ tag which references different users. example: '@username'. I want to make this tag clickable with a link. Sort of insert it as an anchor tag:

```
<a>@username</a>
```

so far I have tried to string manipulate it manually, and inserting the anchor tag inside the string. However this just shows up as plain text in the view.

How do I go about this in Angular 5?

Comment: try `<p [innerHTML]="post.content"></p>`

Comment: yeah but keep in mind, that if you use innerHtml in order to generate html on the fly, you will have to make sure to be safe against xss attacks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have to use the `innerHTML` property to render the provided string as HTML,
so instead of

```
<p> {{post.content}} </p>
```

You should use

```
<p [innerHTML]="post.content"></p>
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/innherhtml)

However, this method is [not safe](https://angular.io/guide/security#xss) and is prone to XSS if not handled properly,

---

**The recommended method:** Create a pipe with DOM Sanitization

**linkify.pipe.ts**

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({
  name: 'linkify'
})
export class LinkifyPipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor(private _domSanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
    return this._domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this.stylize(value));
  }

  // Modify this method according to your custom logic
  private stylize(text: string): string {
    let stylizedText: string = '';
    if (text && text.length > 0) {
      for (let t of text.split(" ")) {
        if (t.startsWith("@") && t.length>1)
          stylizedText += `<a href="#${t.substring(1)}">${t}</a> `;
        else
          stylizedText += t + " ";
      }
      return stylizedText;
    }
    else return text;
  }

}
```

You can modify the `stylize` method according to your logic.

**Usage:**

```
<p [innerHTML]="sample | linkify"></p>
```

[Demo Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/linkify-pipe-jmvjdd)

Comment: this works. The only problem I've found is that the link actually re-loads the angular SPA page.

Answer (score 3):

[cyberpirate92](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48450041/8088021)'s answer is great, though it has one issue: if a link is at the end of the line, the \n will cause the next word on the next line will get captured as well.

I adapted their answer to work on http links as well:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({ name: 'linkify' })
export class LinkifyPipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor(private _domSanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
    return this._domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this.stylize(value));
  }

  // Modify this method according to your custom logic
  private stylize(text: string): string {
    let stylizedText: string = '';
    if (text && text.length > 0) {
      for (let line of text.split("\n")) {
        for (let t of line.split(" ")) {
          if (t.startsWith("http") && t.length>7) {  
            stylizedText += `<a href="${t}">${t}</a> `;
          }
          else
            stylizedText += t + " ";
        }
        stylizedText += '<br>';
      }
      return stylizedText;
    }
    else return text;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Accepted answer works, but I suggest "transform" function to be :

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform, SecurityContext } from '@angular/core';

...

transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
  return this._domSanitizer.sanitize(SecurityContext.HTML, this.stylize(value));
}
```

instead of :

```
transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
  return this._domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this.stylize(value));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

1. I have done related text transform.

   private textLinkify(value: any): any {
   let convertedHTML: string = '';
   var str = 'Click here to know more.';
   var linkStartPos = str.indexOf("{");
   var linkEndPos = str.indexOf("}");

   ```
    let previousText = str.slice(0,linkStartPos);
    let linkText = str.slice(linkStartPos+1,linkEndPos);
    let afterLinkText = str.substr(linkEndPos+2);
    convertedHTML = `${previousText}
    `<a href="${value.href}" target="_blank">${linkText}</a> ${afterLinkText}`;

    return convertedHTML;
   ```

   }

Comment: you can use pipe and call above function.ex
 <span [innerHTML]="text | safe: 'html'"></span>